# Como carregar um .jar externo no Java 11

Tags: java, java-11

É possível carregar um **.jar** externo no **Classloader** do **Java 11**?

Consigo fazer isso na versão 8 do Java, mas a partir do 9 o método para isso acaba sendo quebrado (porque é considerado uma falha de segurança e o Classloader funciona diferente).

No Java 8 o método para isso *(utilizando reflection)* é:

```java
public static void addClassPathURL(File jar) throws Exception {
    Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), new Object[] { jar.toURI().toURL() });
}
```

Se for possível, pode me dar algum exemplo aqui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente executar da seguinte maneira usando o `getSystemClassLoader`:

```java
public static void addClassPathURL(File jar) throws Exception {

    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    try {
        Method method = classLoader.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(classLoader, jar.toURI().toURL());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Method method = classLoader.getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("appendToClassPathForInstrumentation", String.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(classLoader, jar.getPath());
    }

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Estava procurando isso a bastante tempo, pra um projeto que tenho feito. Agora vou poder atualiza-lo para o Java 11+. Entrei em diversos lugares procurando sobre isso, e não achava, só achava sobre o Java 8.